# On OS X El Capitan, what is the difference between /Library/ and /System/Library/?

Tags: macos, library

There are two 'Library' directories in my OS X 10.11 installation, one being /Library/, the other being /System/Library/.

What is the difference between different Library folders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in all the Unix system, there are two type of `lib` folder.

One specific for the user and the other for the entire system and so all the users of the machine.

In particular for OS X: the Macintosh HD version is the actual computer Library, while, the home folder version is specific to your user account.

---

Here an example to help you understand how to use it:

`/System/Library` is a place to store fonts, screen savers, Dashboard widgets, and all other things that all local users need access to.

`~/Library` is for your own user account only (cache and preference files, widgets for your use only, etc).

---

EDIT: taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286571/what-does-mac-os-library-folder-store), a complete overview of all the possible library folders in a Mac OS X system:

- The user library, ~/Library, stores per-user settings etc.
- The local library, /Library, stores computer-wide settings and all-users content etc. I call this the "local" library, because in NextStep it was /Local/Library, but you'll see all sorts of other names for it, such as the root library, computer library, ...
- The network library, /Network/Library would store settings shared by all computers in a network domain -- if a network domain admin set one up, which nobody does anymore...
- The system library, /System/Library, stores the base settings, resources, etc that come with OS X. In theory, you shouldn't change anything in here.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was that there is one _Library_ directory in the root directory (/Library/), and another _Library_ directory in the _System_ directory, which itself is in the root directory (/System/Library/). I'm aware that there is a third _Library_ directory in the user's directory, /Users/_username_/Library/, but this is not what I meant.

Comment: @AlexIxeras in that case take a look at this complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286571/what-does-mac-os-library-folder-store

Comment: @Mattia, Nope, the link doesn't answer it. You've completely missed the question.  `/System/Library` is probably a misnomer; it should've been called `/Library/System`

Answer (score 10):

`/System/Library` is for stuff that doesn't change and is installed by Apple. Files here help the operating system run.

`/Library` is for things that may change and that pertain to all users on a computer.

And for completeness (although not mentioned in the question):

`~/Library` is where things that may change specific to a particular user go.

Comment: this is a better answer

Answer (score 2):

macOS has 3 types of `Libraries`.

Here are the following:

`/Library/` - Used to control system wide settings that are used by all users

*Usually no reason for regular user to alter, although applications will alter this during and post installation*

`/System/Library/` - Same as `/Library/` but protected by SIP. Used by macOS as the core `Library`. Most things in there are required by macOS.

*Shouldn't (and can't without SIP being disabled) be altered.*

`~/Library/` - Same as `/Library/` but for user specific things (Each user has one.

---

You can access each of these by going to Finder>Go>Go To Folder and typing in their respective path.